# Unit Tests for a function with MessageBox

Tags: c#, unit-testing, messagebox

I have a function with custom message boxes like,

```
public bool SomeFunction()
{
   MessageBoxResult mResult= MessageBox.Show("Displaying message");
   bool result;
   if(mResult == MessageBoxResult.OK)
   {
     result = AnyFunction();
   }
    return result;
}
```

And I want to write a unit test for such methods without displaying the message boxes. Is there any way to do this? I am using 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools'

Comment: Could you leverage DI, create a `IMessageBox` which will hide the real implementation and then inject that into original context? Then you can mock real behavior behind the `ìnterface`...

Answer (score 2):

This could be one approach, using `moq`. The idea is to hide real message box implementation behind the interface and then mock its behavior depending what you want to achieve within the test.

**Implementation**

```
public interface IMessageBox
{
    MessageBoxResult Show(string msg);
}

public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IMessageBox _messageBox;

    public SomeClass(IMessageBox messageBox)
    {
        _messageBox = messageBox;
    }

    public bool SomeFunction()
    {
        MessageBoxResult mResult = _messageBox.Show("Displaying message");
        bool result;
        if(mResult == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            result = AnyFunction();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Unit test:**

```
Mock<IMessageBox> messageBoxMock = new Mock<IMessageBox>();
messageBoxMock.Setup(m => m.Show(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(MessageBoxResult.OK); //can be whatever depends on test case
SomeClass sut = new SomeClass(messageBoxMock.Object);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you have static class's method calls, in order to make code testable, create wrapper class for static class and inject wrapper into client.

```
public interface IMessageBoxWrapper 
{
     MessageBoxResult Show(string message);
}

public class MessageBoxWrapper : IMessageBoxWrapper
{

    public MessageBoxResult Show(string message)
    { 

        return MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
 }

 public class SomeClass 
 {

      private readonly IMessageBoxWrapper _messageBox;

      public SomeClass(IMessageBoxWrapper messageBox)
      {
          _messageBox = messageBox;
      }

      public void SomeFunction()
      {              
          MessageBoxResult mResult= _messageBox.Show("Displaying message");
          bool result;
          if(mResult == MessageBoxResult.OK)
          {
            result = AnyFunction();
          }
          return result;
      } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is so many answers on this topic that vary from creating a custom class to using third party libraries. I would say use a third party library if you want cool pop ups with nice visuals.

But if you just want to use the regular message box from microsoft for your WPF app here is an MVVM/unit test friendly implementation:

Initially I thought I would just inherit from message box and wrap it with an interface but I couldn't due to Message box not having a public constructor, so here is the "easy" solution:

Decompiling Message box in visual studio you can see all the method overloads, I checked which ones I wanted then created a new class and added the methods, wrapped it with an interface and ta-da! Now you can use ninject to bind the interface and class, inject it and use Moq to unit test e.t.c.

Create an interface (only added a few of the overloads as I don't need them all):

```
public interface IMessageBox
    {
        /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message, title bar caption, and button; and that returns a result.</summary>          
        MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button);

    /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message, title bar caption, button, and icon; and that returns a result.</summary>           
    MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon);

    /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message and title bar caption; and that returns a result.</summary>            
    MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption);
}
```

Then we have the class that will inherit from it:

```
public class MessageBoxHelper : IMessageBox
    {
        /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message, title bar caption, button, and icon; and that returns a result.</summary>            
        public MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button,
            MessageBoxImage icon)
        {
            return MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon, MessageBoxResult.None,
                MessageBoxOptions.None);
        }

    /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message, title bar caption, and button; and that returns a result.</summary>            
    public MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, MessageBoxImage.None, MessageBoxResult.None,
            MessageBoxOptions.None);
    }

    /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message and title bar caption; and that returns a result.</summary>            
    public MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.None,
            MessageBoxResult.None, MessageBoxOptions.None);
    }

    /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message and that returns a result.</summary>           
    public MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, string.Empty, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.None,
            MessageBoxResult.None, MessageBoxOptions.None);
    }
}
```